# How to disable/enable network connection from a android application?

Tags: android, networking

Setting the device into flight mode can disable all the network connection but i want to disable/enable calls, sms, and gprs/3g from my android program.

Is there any way to do this. ??

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setNetworkPreference%28int%29) or [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29) or [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html#setState%28int%29)?